# Python 3.6 Identifying a string and if X in Y

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newb programmer here working on my first project. I've searched this site and the python documentation, and either I'm not seeing the answer, or I'm not using the right terminology. I've read the regex and if sections, specifically, and followed links around to other parts that seemed relevant.

```
import re

keyphrase = '@@' + '' + '@@'

print(keyphrase) #output is @@@@

j = input('> ') #@@whatever@@

if keyphrase in j:
    print('yay')
else:
    print('you still haven\'t figured it out...')

k = j.replace('@', '')
print(k) #whatever
```

This is for a little reddit bot project. I want the bot to be called like @@whatever@@ and then be able to do things with the word(s) in between the @@'s. I've set up the above code to test if Python was reading it but I keep getting my "you still haven't figured it out..." quip.

I tried adding the REGEX \W in the middle of keyphrase, to no avail. Also weird combinations of \$\$ and quotes

So, my question, is how do I put a placeholder in keyphrase for user input?

For instance, if a @@comment@@ does something like @@this@@ @@I can grab@@ everything between the @ symbols as separate inputs/calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import re

keyphrase_regex = re.compile(r'@@(.*)@@')

user_input = input('> ') 

keyphrase_match = keyphrase_regex.search(user_input)
# `search` returns `None` if regex didn't match anywhere in the string
keyphrase_content = keyphrase_match.group(1) if keyphrase_match else None

if keyphrase_content:
    keyphrase_content = keyphrase_match.group(1)
    print('yay! You submitted "', keyphrase_content, '" to the bot!')

else:  
    # Bonus tip: Use double quotes to make a string containing apostrophe 
    #            without using a backslash escape
    print("you still haven't figured it out...")

# Use `keyphrase_content` for whatever down here
```

Regular expressions are kind of hard to wrap your head around, because they work differently than most programming constructs. It's a language to describe patterns.

[Regex One](https://regexone.com/) is a fantastic beginners guide.

[Regex101](http://regex101.com) is an online sandbox that allows you to type a regular expression and some sample strings, then see what matches (and why) in real time

The regex `@@(.*)@@` basically means "search through the string until you find two '@' signs. Right after those, start capturing zero-or-more of any character. If you find another '@', stop capturing characters. If that '@' is followed by another one, stop looking at the string, return successfully, and hold onto the entire match (from first '@' to last '@'). Also, hold onto the captured characters in case the programmer asks you for *just them*.

**EDIT**: Props to @ospahiu for bringing up the `?` lazy quantifier. A final solution, combining our approaches, would look like this:

```
# whatever_bot.py

import re

# Technically, Python >2.5 will compile and cache regexes automatically.
# For tiny projects, it shouldn't make a difference. I think it's better style, though.
# "Explicit is better than implicit"
keyphrase_regex = re.compile(r'@@(.*?)@@')

def parse_keyphrases(input):
    return keyphrase_regex.find_all(input)
```

Lambdas are cool. I prefer them for one-off things, but the code above is something I'd rather put in a module. Personal preference.

You could even make the regex substitutable, using the '@@' one by default

```
# whatever_bot.py

import re

keyphrase_double_at_sign = re.compile(r'@@(.*?)@@')

def parse_keyphrases(input, keyphrase_regex=keyphrase_double_at_sign):
    return keyphrase_regex.find_all(input)
```

You could even go bonkers and write a function that generates a keyphrase regex from an arbitrary "tag" pattern! I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;) Just remember: Several characters have special regex meanings, like '*' and '?', so if you want to match that literal character, you'd need to escape them (e.g. '\?').

Comment: This was spot on, thank you. One follow up, the (.*) part, is there a way to make it identify it only when there an alphanum directly after the opening @@ and prior to the ending @@. When I tested:

> well $$i hope this$$ works better $$maybe not$$ though
yay! You submitted " i hope this$$ works better $$maybe not " to the bot!

when I was expecting 'i hope this' and 'maybe not' instead

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible. I missed the part where you wanted to capture all "instances" in the user string. @ospahiu has the solution in his answer. Using `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` tells the regex engine to match *as few characters as possible*

Comment: `.` Means "any character". Implicitly, we want "any character... except two '@'". And that's what `?` does there. Basically increasing the priority of the pattern that comes *next* after the pattern quantified by `*`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex `r'@@(.*?)@@'` to capture everything inside of the key phrase you've chosen.

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> import re
>>> f = lambda s: re.match(r'@@(.*?)@@', s).group(1)
>>> f("@@whatever@@")
whatever
>>> f = lambda s: re.findall(r'@@(.*?)@@', s)  
>>> f("a @@comment@@ does something like @@this@@ @@I can grab@@ everything between the @ symbols as separate inputs/calls.")
['comment', 'this', 'I can grab']
```

How does it work? **(1)** We state the string constant head and tail for the capture group 1 between the brackets `()`. Great, almost there! **(2)** We then match any character `.*?` with greedy search enforced so that we capture the whole string.

**Suggested Readings:**

- [Introduction to Regex in Python - Jee Gikera](https://scotch.io/tutorials/an-introduction-to-regex-in-python)

Comment: Thank you! I spent a lot of time reading into lambda and your code learning what it does. The greedy search really helped out. I didn't think this code would be this, relatively, complicated. The suggested reading helped out a ton too.

Comment: Also, I was having trouble translating the python code into a python program. I understand how to put it in PowerShell but getting it into a .py was/is hard. In PS, could I have done var = "a @@comment@@..." and then written f = lambda var: re.findall(r'@@(.*?)@@, var) and get the same output?

Comment: No worries @johnnycodes! Yes, you would essentially assign that string constant to a new variable which you can then pass around to a function! Note that the name of the variable does not have to be of the same name as the function parameter `var`. You can name that string variable anything you'd like and then _pass it as an argument_ to the function.

Comment: Anyways, keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the content between the "@", then try this:

```
j = input("> ")

"".join(j.split("@"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any of the info between the @'s in your example because you're effectively looking for '@@@@' in whatever input you give it.  Unless you happen to put 4 @'s in a row, that RE will never match.

What you want to do instead is something like
 `re.match('@@\W+@@', j)`

which will look for 2 leading @@s, then any number greater than 1 alphanumeric characters (\W+), then 2 trailing @@s.  From there, your strip code looks fine and you should be able to grab it.